# Android deep linking path pattern

Tags: android, xml, deep-linking

i have this url https://myportal.net/#!/search/main/34 i need to implemnt deep linking when user click on the url its open the app.

Note: 34 number is changing in the url

i do the following but its not working

```
 <activity
        android:name="ui.Activities.SplashActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"


        android:theme="@style/SplashScreen">

        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="${hostName}"
                android:pathPattern="/.*/.*/.*/.*"
                android:scheme="https" />

        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Try using the App Links Assistant of Android Studio: Tools > App Links Assistant. It will help you to check if the pattern is correct or not

Comment: thank you i solve the issue by android:pathPattern="/.*" to support open app

Answer (score 1):

In Your Splash Activity

```
private void handleDeepLink(Intent intent) {
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
.getDynamicLink(intent)
.addOnSuccessListener(pendingDynamicLinkData -> {
// Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
Uri deepLink;
String finalLink = "";
        if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {

            deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();


            String string = String.valueOf(deepLink);
            String decodeUrl = Utils.decodeUrl(string);

            String[] parts = decodeUrl.split("main/");
            String part1= parts[0]; 

            String part2= parts[1];

            finalLink = part2.replaceAll(" ", "+");

            Log.w("dynamiclink", finalLink);
            if (!Validator.isEmptyString(finalLink)) {
                getDataManager().setAuthSecret(finalLink);
            }
        }
        getNavigator().openRegistrationActivity(finalLink);
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(e -> {

        getNavigator().openRegistrationActivity("");
    });`
}
```

In your Manifiest file

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<data
        android:host="nms-rx.in"
        android:pathPrefix="main/"
        android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: thank you i solve the issue by  android:pathPattern="/.*"
to support open app